# TSQL - Control a number sequence

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Im a new in TSQL.
I have a table with a field called ODOMETER of a vehicle. I have to get the quantity of km in a period of time from 1st of the month to the end.
SELECT MAX(Odometer) - MIN(Odometer) as TotalKm FROM Table 
This will work in ideal test scenary, but the Odomometer can be reset to 0 in anytime.
Someone can help to solve my problem, thank you.

I'm working with MS SQL 2012

EXAMPLE of records:

```
 Date          Odometer value
 datetime var, 37210
 datetime var, 37340
 datetime var, 0
 datetime var, 220
```

Comment: Please show the relevant schema and a sequence of data that is problematic so we have a better.

Comment: Which database system is it?

Comment: In your example data if the dates were say 3/1,3/10,3/20,and 3/31 that would cover March and you would want a sum that accounted for the reset, right? Sum = (37240-37210) + (220-0)?

Comment: That's right, I dont know how to detect the change and sum partials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this using the LAG. There are other ways, but this should be easy.

EDIT: Changing the sample data to include records outside of the desired month range. Also simplifying that Reading for easy hand calc. Will shows a second option as siggested by OP.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (stamp DATETIME, Reading INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
  ('02/28/2014',0)
 ,('03/01/2014',10)
 ,('03/10/2014',20)
 ,('03/22/2014',0)
 ,('03/30/2014',10)
 ,('03/31/2014',20)
 ,('04/01/2014',30)

--Original solution with WHERE on the "outer" SELECT.
--This give a result of 40 as it include the change of 10 between 2/28 and 3/31. 

;WITH cte AS (
   SELECT Reading
         ,LAG(Reading,1,Reading) OVER (ORDER BY stamp ASC) LastReading
         ,Reading - LAG(Reading,1,Reading) OVER (ORDER BY stamp ASC) ChangeSinceLastReading 
         ,CONVERT(date, stamp) stamp
     FROM @tbl
)
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Reading = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ChangeSinceLastReading END)
  FROM cte
 WHERE stamp BETWEEN '03/01/2014' AND '03/31/2014'

--Second option with WHERE on the "inner" SELECT (within the  CTE)
--This give a result of 30 as it include the change of 10 between 2/28 and 3/31 is by the filtered lag.

;WITH cte AS (
   SELECT Reading
         ,LAG(Reading,1,Reading) OVER (ORDER BY stamp ASC) LastReading
         ,Reading - LAG(Reading,1,Reading) OVER (ORDER BY stamp ASC) ChangeSinceLastReading 
         ,CONVERT(date, stamp) stamp
     FROM @tbl
    WHERE stamp BETWEEN '03/01/2014' AND '03/31/2014'
)
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Reading = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ChangeSinceLastReading END)
  FROM cte
```

Comment: +1 for the use of [LAG function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for answer, Karl, I will try your solution later. I will comment later and vote.

Comment: Karl, I have corrected the script, now it's working fine.  You can test changing the WHERE clause. Thank you very much.

Comment: I looked at your proposed edit.  The addition of more records will help clarify the behavior, but moving the WHERE clause has an interesting effect. I'll see if I can edit myself to show both.

Answer (score 0):

I think Karl solution using LAG is better than mine, but anyway:

```
;WITH [Rows] AS
(
    SELECT o1.[Date], o1.[Value] as CurrentValue, 
                (SELECT TOP 1 o2.[Value] 
                FROM @tbl o2 WHERE o1.[Date] < o2.[Date]) as NextValue
    FROM @tbl o1
)
SELECT SUM (CASE WHEN [NextValue] IS NULL OR [NextValue] < [CurrentValue] THEN 0 ELSE [NextValue] - [CurrentValue] END )
FROM [Rows]
```